# XDocument getting Root Attributes values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xattribute

How can I get the value of title1 from this string in a datatable using xDocument

```
<Person ActionType = "Update"  Title1="Miss" />
```

I tried descendants, XAttributes and all sorts...Maybe input is wrong but

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(row["XMLTransaction"].ToString());

IEnumerable<XAttribute> query =
from transaction in xml.Root.Elements()
select transaction.Attribute(attribute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that string is your literal XML then you should omit the `.Elements()` part.

Even shorter with XElement instead of XDocument :

```
 var xml = XElement.Parse(row["XMLTransaction"].ToString());

 IEnumerable<XAttribute> query = xml.Attributes();
```

Comment: Well that did it thanks. Just wish there was some website tutorial - maybe i need to improve my googling

Comment: By the way, how do I get the value? I've been trying all morning

Comment: `query2 = xml.Attributes().Select(a => a.Value);` gives an `IEnum<string>`

Comment: xattributes do not contain a definition for 'Select'. i can iterate through them using foreach but wondered best way of accessing the value of the attribute

Comment: It's an extension method, you need `using System.Linq;`